# Webgl gl.viewport change

Tags: webgl, viewport

I have a problem with canvas resizing and `gl.viewport` sync.
Let's say that I start with both the canvas [300x300 canvas](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/96108589/shapes-300x300.png), and the initialization of `gl.viewport` at the same sizes (`gl.vieport(0, 0, 300, 300)`).
After that, in browser's console I make my tests:

1. [I'm changing size of my canvas](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/96108589/shapes-200x200.png), using jquery, calling something like `$("#scene").width(200).height(200)`
2. [After this, i'm calling my resizeWindow function](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/96108589/shapes-200x200-resize-200x200.png):

   ```
   function resizeWindow(width, height){
       var ww = width === undefined? w.gl.viewportWidth : width;
       var h = height  === undefined? w.gl.viewportHeight : height;
       h = h <= 0? 1 : h;
       w.gl.viewport(0, 0, ww, h);
       mat4.identity(projectionMatrix);
       mat4.perspective(45, ww / h, 1, 1000.0, projectionMatrix);
       mat4.identity(modelViewMatrix);
   }
   ```

   - function that's synchronizing viewport with required dimensions.

Unfortunatly, my `gl.viewport` after this call takes only a part of my canvas.
Could anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such thing is `gl.viewportWidth` or `gl.viewportHeight`

If you want to set your perspective matrix you should use `canvas.clientWidth` and `canvas.clientHeight` as your inputs to perspective. Those will give you the correct results regardless of what size the browser scales the canvas. As in if you set the canvas auto scale with css

```
<canvas style="width: 100%; height:100%;"></canvas>

...

var width = canvas.clientHeight;
var height = Math.max(1, canvas.clientHeight);  // prevent divide by 0
mat4.perspective(45, width / height, 1, 1000, projectionMatrix);
```

As for the viewport. Use `gl.drawingBufferWidth` and `gl.drawingBufferHeight`. That's the correct way to find the size of your drawingBuffer

```
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
```

Just to be clear there are several things conflated here

- `canvas.width`, `canvas.height` = size you requested the canvas's drawingBuffer to be
- `gl.drawingBufferWidth`, `gl.drawingBufferHeight` = size you actually got. In 99.99% of cases this will be the same as `canvas.width`, `canvas.height`.
- `canvas.clientWidth`, `canvas.clientHeight` = size the browser is displaying your canvas.

To see the difference

```
<canvas width="10" height="20" style="width: 30px; height: 40px"></canvas>
```

or

```
canvas.width = 10;
canvas.height = 20;
canvas.style.width = "30px";
canvas.style.height = "40px";
```

In these cases `canvas.width` will be 10, `canvas.height` will be 20, `canvas.clientWidth` will be 30, `canvas.clientHeight` will be 40. It's common to set `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height` to a percentage so that the browser scales it to fit whatever element it is contained in.

On top of that there are the 2 things you brought up

- viewport = generally you want this to be the size of your drawingBuffer
- aspect ratio = generally you want this to be the size your canvas is scaled to

Given those definitions the width and height used for `viewport` is often not the same as the width and height used for `aspect ratio`.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstand around gl.viewportWidth or gl.viewportHeight, these parameters assigned in moment after initializes gl object (js feature), so gl.viewportWidth = canvas.clientWidth and gl.viewportHeight = canvas.clientHeight. 
Also, if this things was misspelled they would be corrected, but problem appears when I try to manual call resizeWindow, in case when transmitted parameters  they should be dominant (see code).<br/> For gl.drawingBufferWidth and gl.drawingBufferHeight great thanks, it's really helped me